# Lining up two sets of columns

Tags: html, css

I have a page layout as shown here...
http://jsfiddle.net/k55DE/

What I need is for the left edge of the two pink columns to always line up no matter how wide the screen is. The Sidebar container is always 300px wide,

Thanks for any help

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="toolbar">
        <div id="nav">NAVIGATION</div>
        <div id="search">SEARCH</div>
    </div>
    <div id="site">
        <div id="content">CONTENT</div>
        <div id="sidebar">SIDEBAR</div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>​
```

-

```
#toolbar {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    overflow:auto;
}

#toolbar #nav,
#toolbar #search {
    float:left;
}

#toolbar #nav {
    background-color:#ddffdd;
    min-height:30px;
    text-align:right;
    width:66%;
}

#toolbar #search {
    background-color:#ffdddd;
    min-height:50px;
    width:34%;
}



#site {
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
    width:800px;
}

#site #content,
#site #sidebar {
    float:left;
    min-height:300px;
}

#site #content {
    background-color:#ddffdd;
    text-align:right;
    width:70%;
}

#site #sidebar {
    background-color:#ffdddd;
    width:30%;
}
​
```

Comment: @shareef: Looks like jsFiddle is down.

Comment: -1 this is why you place relative code in the question and not an external resource.

Comment: Why mark me down because jsfiddle is down? The question is easier to understand with a working example

Comment: @michael I marked you down because your code is not in your question. The idea is that your question and the answers provided will help others in the future. If JSFiddle stops existing then how can your question help people? Anyway, downvote removed since you have now added the code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is to make sure the right-side of the green areas is always lined up. In theory, this can be done by making the green areas always be the same size. Unfortunately, this is much harder than it would otherwise be because the upper green area has a percentage width (66%) and the lower green area has an explicit width (70% of 800px or ~560px). Oh, and the lower green area is centered.

Because the lower "content" area has been centered (margin-left and margin-right are auto), the margin on the left will be some fixed amount based on the size of the browser window. (Approximately (browser width - 800)/2.) Since this value is dependent on the width of your browser at the time of rendering, you cannot determine this amount in pure CSS and will need to use JavaScript to force these to line up.

The Javascript would need to do the following:

1. Determine the width of the left margin (browser width - 800px)/2, approximately.
2. Set the width of the upper green part to be margin width (as calculated in 1) + 800px. Set the upper pink part to fill the rest horizontally.
3. Add a listener to the window resize action and repeat 1 and 2 above every time the window is resized.

This would all be much simpler if either the bottom part was not centered or if the top part also had the same centering/sizing applied. Then you'd be able to apply a pure CSS solution.